# printing issue in C#

Tags: c#, angularjs, html, css, printing

I have a ANgular JS HTML5 CSS3, Web APi MVC based app and it has a page that user can right click and print. Now I have to hide certain links like chatbox etc in print which I did using no-print class that I got from internet.

Now, the issue is, some very few words or lines aren't printed at only certain pages. When I right click in print preview, all is fine. What could be the issue? I am so confused or puzzled.

**EDIT**

This is not reproducible always, as because, what happens is, I tried in another printer and in that 2nd printout, I found that some other texts in the margin top are missing while in the first printout, the texts in the down margin was missing (Please remember, in both cases, some textx in the same margins were printed but only few pages it wasn't printing the margin texs)

Well puzzled, please direct me

**EDIT**

**It works perfectly fine (Prints everything in Landscape mode)**

Comment: Buy a new printer.

Comment: @charlietfl: lol that my employer needs to do :D

Comment: @charlietfl: Resolved as the issue was some components weren't hidden and it was blocking the texts